# Для чего нужно использовал JPanel и можно ли обойтись только JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jframe, jpanel

Я имею несколько простых элементов типа JButton, JTable, JTextField и т.д.
Мне нужно просто вывести их в окно, и повесить событие на JButton.
Нужно ли и зачем в данном случае использовать еще и JPanel, чтобы вначале все перечисленные элементы разместить на ней, а потом уже саму панель разместить на JFrame? Если да, то чем это обосновывается?

Comment: Если не хотите - не используйте.

Comment: Вопрос стоит о целесообразности использования JFrame + JPanel?

Comment: это контейнерный компонент, если Вы все сваливаете в кучу - он Вам не нужен, если же Вы хотите раздетить компоненты на, допустим 2 группы - можно использовать для этого 2 панели.

Comment: хорошо, а если я повешу событие на JButton при котором у меня будет появляться JTable в том же самом окне, есть ли смысл тогда использовать JPanel?

Comment: как пожелаете :) они в целом, для Вашего удобства

Comment: у JPanel больше возможностей для форматирования лейаутов? или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2):

Да JFrame можно использовать без JPanel, ну а JPanel удобно использовать для расположения нескольких элементов и их группировки например с другими JPanel.

Comment: а если я буду использовать только кнопки (с событиями), текстовые поля и таблицы в одном окне, нужен ли еще будет JPanel? другие панели мне явно будут не нужны, выходит в теории мне нужно не более одной панели

Comment: я имел ввиду , когда  у тебя много различных элементов то распределив их по разным JPanel , удобнее их так группировать . Понятно что  если у тебя пару кнопок и пару текствью то JPanel ненужен совсем